# Java Array Index out of Bounds Error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a brute force approach to the traveling salesman problem. I have a certain line that produces the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception, however all the arrays used there have more than enough space. The particular line of code:

```
testCity[0][a] = cities[0][(int) cityList[a]];
```

This is where I initialize `testCity`:

```
int[][] testCity = new int[2][CITIES+10];
```

`cities`:

```
public static int[][] cities = new int[2][CITIES+10];
```

And, finally, `cityList`:

```
Object[] cityList = new Integer[CITIES+10];
```

This is the entire error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at BruteF.permute(BruteF.java:39)
at BruteF.permute(BruteF.java:30)
at BruteF.permute(BruteF.java:30)
at BruteF.permute(BruteF.java:30)
at BruteF.main(BruteF.java:11)
```

And here is the code:

```
public class BruteF {
public static final int CITIES = 5;
public static int[][] cities = new int[2][CITIES+10];
public static int[][] bestCity = new int[2][CITIES+10];
public static double bestDistance = 1000;
public static int[][] testCity = new int[2][CITIES+10];
public static Object[] cityList = new Integer[CITIES+10];
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    permute(java.util.Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4), 0);
    for (int i = 0;i < CITIES;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(bestCity[0][i] + "," + bestCity[1][i]);
    }
}
static void permute(java.util.List<Integer> arr, int k){
    cities[0][0] = 1;
    cities[1][0] = 1;
    cities[0][1] = 2;
    cities[1][1] = 5;
    cities[0][2] = 3;
    cities[1][2] = 2;
    cities[0][3] = 4;
    cities[1][3] = 3;
    int originalX = cities[0][0];
    int originalY = cities[1][0];
    for(int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++){
        java.util.Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
        permute(arr, k+1);
        java.util.Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
    }
    if (k == arr.size() -1){
        for (int i = 0;i < CITIES;i++)
        {
            cityList = arr.toArray();
            for (int a = 0;a < CITIES;a++)
            {
                testCity[0][a] = cities[0][(int) cityList[a]];
            }
            if (distance(testCity,CITIES,originalX, originalY) < bestDistance)
            {
                bestCity = testCity;
                bestDistance = distance(testCity,CITIES, originalX, originalY);
            }
        }
    }
}
static double distance (int[][] cities, int CITIES, int originalX, int originalY)
{
    int[][] taken = new int[2][CITIES+1];
    int takenCounter = 0;
    double distance = 0;
    cities[0][CITIES] = cities[0][0];
    cities[1][CITIES] = cities[1][0];
    for (int i = 0;i <= CITIES;i++)
    {
        for (int z = 0;z <= CITIES;z++)
        {
            if (cities[0][i] == taken[0][z] && cities[1][i] == taken[1][z])
            {
                return CITIES*1000; //possible error here
            }
            else {
            taken[0][takenCounter] = cities[0][i];
            taken[1][takenCounter] = cities[1][i];
            }
        }
        if (cities[0][0] != originalX && cities[1][0] != originalY)
        {
        return CITIES*1000;                             //POSSIBLE BUG HERE
        }
        distance = distance + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cities[0][i+1]-cities[0][i],2) + Math.pow(cities[1][i+1]-cities[1][i],2));
    }
    return distance;
}
}
```

Why is this happenening? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Whatever is in `cityList[a]` is greater than or equal to `CITIES+10`. Also, why are you declaring `cityList` as `Object[]` instead of `Integer[]`?

Comment: @resueman The loop that declares `a` is `for (int a = 0;a < CITIES;a++)`. Also, I declare `cityList` as an `Object[]` because in another part of the program, if I change it to `Integer[]`, it produces the error `Cannot convert from Object[] to Integer[]`

Comment: Unknown code cause exception with unknown stack trace. How could we find the bug?

Comment: @JBNizet Should I include the entire code?

Comment: You should post the minimum amount of code necessary to identify the problem, and the complete stack trace of the exception. That at least includes the code that is referenced from the stack trace, i.e. the code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @JBNizet, OK, did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving out of bound exception : 4
when you are initializing cityList  i.e. cityList = arr.toArray(); your array cityList[] = {1,2,3,4} , i.e of size 4 from 0 to 3.
And you are running a for loop i.e

```
for (int a = 0;a < CITIES;a++)
```

from a=0 to CITIES , so as the moment arrive when a=4, it gives out of bound error.

Comment: General suggestion : you should debug it your self before asking for help. if you use eclipse then you can use debugger.